# how to pass parameters to xsl file and use it to response

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

i have and xsl file which is rendering the question on UI. 
The Question are distributed in different catagory.

Now my requirement is to pass the parameter from java code to xsl file and on the basis of that parameter i would like to perform specific operation to generate the UI.

Can Any body help me out in suggesting how to pass parameter to XSL file from JAVA code ?

Example:

```
/form/A/Question-Category,
/form/B/Question-Category,
/form/c/Question-Category,
/form/D/Question-Category
```

A,B,C,D are categories which I will pass from java code and use that token to get my XPATh of question
Say if token passed from java code is B, then expression will be `'/form/B/Question-Category'` .

Now my hurdle is i dont know how to pass the parameter from java code and how i can use it in XSL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the parameter like this:

```
<xsl:param name="category"/>
```

Use it like this

```
select="/form/*[name()=$category]/Question-Category
```

Then pass it from Java like this (assuming you are using the JAXP API):

```
transformer.setParameter("category", "a");
```

I don't think this is a particularly smart XML document design by the way. I think the list of categories is data rather than metadata, so I would use `<category name="A">` rather than `<A>` to define category A. But your course tutor may have other ideas (I assume this is a student exercise, because implementing a questionnaire usually is.)

Comment: Thanks . It works . *[name()=$category] - how to read this ? and where i can find the good descriptive tutorial about the same. Other than w3school